# как вставить картинку из базы данных в JavaFx?

Tags: java, sql, listview, javafx, imageview

Есть таблица в БД с картинками и есть list с датами этих картинок.. Нужно чтобы при клике на определенную дату показывалась определенная картинка в ImageView.. получился такой метод:

```
ConnectionHelper ch=new ConnectionHelper();
    ch.Connect();
    String q="SELECT IMG FROM img_ins";

    Statement st=ch.con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(q);

   InputStream is= rs.getBinaryStream("IMG");
    OutputStream os=new FileOutputStream(new File("img.jpg"));
    byte [] content= new byte[1024];
    int size=0;


        while ((size=is.read(content))!=-1){

            os.write(content, 0, size);
        }

    os.close();
    is.close();

    javafx.scene.image.Image image1=new Image("file:img.jpg", image.getFitWidth(), image.getFitHeight(), true, true);
    image.setImage(image1);
    image.setPreserveRatio(true);
}
```

Но отображается ошибка SQLException...[image: SQLException в методе SetImage]

Comment: Уточните - что называется "не компилируется корректно" ? Это то же самоое, что "компилируется не корректно"?

Comment: вылетает SQLException

Comment: Почему вы её не опубликовали? Если решитесь -  [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/666278/edit).